# Boot Trouble: Windows 7/Ubuntu 12

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have a new laptop that has windows 7, and I wanted to dual boot Windows/Ubuntu.  Just like my old one was. So, I downloaded and burned Ubuntu to disk. I then changed the BIOS setting to boot from CD/DVD drive (it's external)

Installed Ubuntu and loader works fine as long as I only want to use Ubuntu.

Problem is, is that when I go to boot Windows, it's looking for a disk.

I can't get to the BIOS, so does anyone know the command to change windows so that it boots from the hard drive?

PS: I don't have a rescue disk.

UPDATE: Tried SuperGrub and now I've lost both. Windows and Ubuntu are both gone from my boot list in BIOS! Can't boot anything!!!

Does anyone have any other suggestions please?? My pc is now completely unusable. That SuperGrup just lists a #13 & a #15 error and no longer changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different laptop models have different BIOS access keys assigned to them. If you can [find your laptop manufacturer and model in this list](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/4178-laptops-access-bios-settings-key), press the corresponding key while your laptop is booting up, **before** you reach the screen allowing you to select an operating system. If your laptop model is not listed on the above site, attempt performing a web search on your Ubuntu partition for your laptop model and the BIOS access key associated with it.

Once you reach BIOS, there should be a setting to change the boot order. Move hard disk drive (HDD) to the top of the list and you should be able to access Windows assuming your Windows installation is not corrupted.

Once again, the link for reference: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/4178-laptops-access-bios-settings-key

Comment: Thank you Jesse I can now enter BIOS! Windows then ran a self check because of the partition change.  It then reconfigured Windows & then after entirely skipping the OS boot options loaded Windows.  Which is great, I can now access Windows!  How can I get the OS selection back though?

Comment: I tried switching the boot order back, so that I can get the OS selection back.  When I select Windows that way, I get the error: error: invalid EFI path file.  What now?

Comment: See Michael Clayton's answer below. That will probably fix your bootloader. http://askubuntu.com/a/334925/92538

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the **Super Grub Disk 0.9799** iso and create a CD from it.
http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot/Super-Grub-Disk-8071.shtml
It can activate partitions, boot partitions, boot MBRs, boot your former OS (Linux or another one) by loading menu.lst from your hard disk, automatically restore Grub on your MBR, swap hard disks in the BIOS, and boot from any available disk device.
Boot from the SGD and then follow the steps on the displayed menus to restore your bootloader.

Comment: Tried SuperGrub and now I've lost both.  Windows and Ubuntu are both gone from my boot list in BIOS!  Can't boot anything!!!

Comment: @justathoughtor2 do you have any other suggestions please??  My pc is now completely unusable.  That SuperGrup just lists a #13 & a #15 error and no longer changes anything.